# 500 error when asp.net session variable times out

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an aspx.cs file where I check if the user's session variable is still good, if it is, do some stuff, if it isn't, write out a response with a div tag back to the page that made the ajax request to it so that the receiving page knows it needs to redirect to the login page.

```
if (Session["AccountID"].ToString() != "" && Session["AccountID"] != null)
    {...do something }
else{Response.Write("<div id="imalogin"></div>)}
```

I thought that I could check if something exists without getting an error, but it gives me an error on the if statement. The error is:

"[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   editOwner.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\BlippohAdminSvn\editOwner.aspx.cs:13 ......"

Line 13 is the if statement

Comment: Error is not becuase Session is null, if session has expired, there still is a new one created fr a page. The problem is, Session["AccountID"] is null and you invoke null.ToString(). Just replace the two checks and the logical operator. Change your test to if ( Session["AccountID"] == null || Session["AccountID"].ToString() == null )

Comment: I mean, the new if statement is the test for an expired login. if true, write the login div. If false, do domething.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check only if the session is null. You are attempting a ToString() on a possibly null value which would give you a NullReferenceException.

```
if (Session["AccountID"] != null)
{...do something }
else{Response.Write("<div id="imalogin"></div>)}
```

Comment: yes, it seems like it can't convert something that is null to a string so the conversion fails. Let me test it.

Comment: that seems to work as expected. I can't mark the answer until 5 mins